# Open Source Mentoring Programmes for Formal Education

Tags: mentoring

I'm exploring options for students to work on open source projects for academic credit. The Apache Software Foundation run a [Mentoring Programme](https://community.apache.org/mentoringprogramme.html), and also facilitate [participating in the Mentoring Programme as part of formal education](https://community.apache.org/mentorprogrammeformaleducation.html).

Are there other programmes like this, where open source organisations will work with a tutor to mentor a student on a real open source project? Also interested to hear if anyone has had experience with the Apache Mentoring programme.

Comment: I can't speak to the Apache Mentoring Program specifically, but informally, I think that many of the larger open source projects have onboarding and mentoring processes designed for beginners.  When my students have gotten involved in the likes of musescore in the past, there is always community support there for beginners to get involved.